# How to obtain cleaned_data from a FormSetView (django-extra-views)

Tags: django

I cannot see how to trigger and obtain the cleaned_data from my FormSetView. With a django formset, I would call `is_valid()` on the formset within a POST'ed response, but not sure how to do that here. Examples in documentation do not show this, afaics.

I've implemented exactly as per the example in django-extra-views documentation. I already have a ModelFormSetView working fine although the DB update is automatic in that case. However, in this case of non-model implementation the cleaned data necessarily needs to be massaged into a different format for DB storage.

My view (called from the url entry):

```
class TemplateFSView(FormSetView):
    template_name = 'template_season.html'
    form_class = TemplateForm
    success_url = 'tee/home/'

    def get_initial(self):
        # initial data is a pre-load test for now...
        return [{'commence': '07:30', 'finish': '22:00', "spacing": "10"]

    def formset_valid(self, formset):
        # do whatever you'd like to do with the valid formset
        print('How do I get here?')
        return super(TemplateFSView, self).formset_valid(formset)
```

Form:

```
class TemplateForm(forms.Form):
    commence = forms.CharField(required=True, label='first tee-time')
    finish = forms.CharField(required=True, label='last tee-time')
    spacing = forms.CharField(required=True, label='tee spacing')
```

Template:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
    {% for form in formset %}
        {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">{{ form.commence.label_tag }}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ form.finish.label_tag }}</th>
                <th scope="col">{{ form.spacing.label_tag }}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.commence }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.finish }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.spacing }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The `formset_valid` method is called when the formset is, well, valid; and it receives the formset as a parameter, so you can access its cleaned_data attribute.

Comment: But "massaging the data" sounds like something that should be done inside the formset itself, in the `clean` method.

Comment: Tks Daniel, I'm trying to find a method that feeds me the formset for manipulation prior to a DB save. I tried defining `def clean(self)` on the `TemplateFSView` class, but that doesn't fire, nor does `formset_valid(self, formset)`. I'm obviously missing something!

Comment: As I said, `clean` is a method on the formset, not the view. But your formset_valid method would fire, if the formset is actually valid; but is your indentation correct? It needs to be indented within the view class.

Comment: Ah ok, sounds like I need to subclass `FormSetView` with my chosen custom behaviours. (Yes, indentation in class methods above are correct, just didn't get displayed correctly, I'll correct that.) Tks for help.